# Atmosphere on iOS / Objective C

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, atmosphere

I plan to use [Atmosphere](https://github.com/Atmosphere/atmosphere) in a iOS app. There is a version to integrate atmosphere with JavaScript but I see no native iOS implementation.

How can I integrate atmosphere in my iOS app?

Comment: Atmosphere is designed for various browsers which are supporting different comet way such as websocket, long-polling, streaming and so on. If you want to apply comet only to iOS app, there is no need to using Atmosphere, native websocket is good for you.